# Identifying 32/64bit Version via Powershell Script

Tags: arrays, powershell

I need to identify if the installed software (several times per host) is an 32bit or 64bit version. To do this I want to check the Execution Folder of the Service via powershell.

This is my first powershell script and I'm a bit lost. I would like to store the information of Get-WmiObject win32_service to a multidimensional array.

If I run the command selecting PathName, State and DisplayName the PathName will be shortened, for that I run this command several times. But don't know how to get is in the right fields of the array or get the right fields in my foreach

Here is what I got so far:

```
`$ServiceArray = @()
$ServiceArray[] = Get-WmiObject win32_service | ?{$_.Name -like 'foo_*'} | 
Select PathName
$ServiceArray[][] = Get-WmiObject win32_service | ?{$_.Name -like 'foo_*'} | 

Select State
$ServiceArray[][][] = Get-WmiObject win32_service | ?{$_.Name -like 'foo_*'} 
| Select DisplayName
foreach($array in $ServiceArray[]) 
   {
    if ($array.Contains(\bin\test\win64\test.exe)
    {
     $ServiceArray[][][][] = "win64"
 }    
 else 
 {
     $ServiceArray[][][][] = "win32"
 }  `
```

I know that it does not work this way, but I don't know how it works correct, either.

Comment: "I would like to store the information [in] a multidimensional array" - *why*? What fields/properties are you interested in?

Answer (score 2):

You can select multiple properties in the same statement with `Select-Object`:

```
$ServiceArray = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service | 
  Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'foo_*'} |
  Select PathName,State,DisplayName
```

You can also use `Select-Object` with a calculated property to add the bitness based on the `PathName` argument if needed:

```
$ServiceArray = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service | 
  Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'foo_*'} |
  Select PathName,State,DisplayName,@{Name='Bitness';Expression={if($_.PathName -like "*Win64*"){"Win64"}else{"Win32"}}}
```

Comment: Note that you can get better performance with `Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter 'Name LIKE "foo_%"'`.  It probably won't matter much for a local query, but over a remote connection it's about 10 times faster to filter with `Get-WmiObject`.

Answer (score 0):

You can select multiple properties. You were almost there. Edited your code a little.

```
$ServiceArray = @()
$ServiceArray = Get-WmiObject win32_service | ?{$_.Name -like 'foo_*'} | Select PathName,State,DisplayName,Architecture
foreach($Element in $ServiceArray) 
{
    if ($Element.PathName.Contains('\bin\test\win64\test.exe'))
    {
        $Element.Architecture = 'win64'
    }    
    else 
    {
        $Element.Architecture = 'win32'
    }
    $Element
}
```